# “Quick simple product creation” - Categories & Websites not configured

Tags: magento, magento-1.6, stock, configurable-product

I’ve been creating simple associated products using the “Quick simple product creation” panel, in Associated Products tabs. I noticed today that the simple products created using this function, do not have any categories or websites assigned. As a result, the parent configurable product is displayed as out of stock.

I manually assigned some categories on these simple products (in Categories tab), and chacked the “Main Website” option (in Websites tab) and the parent conf product became available for sale.

Why is this happening? Do I have to manually set these parameters for all associated simple products?  Isn’t there some way to inherit the parent configurable products categories and websites?

Answer (score 2):

If you create simple products using “Quick simple product creation” then remember to assign any Websites and categories to the configurable product first. If websites are assigned to the Configurable product then the Associated product created this way will also get associated to the respective websites.

Comment: The configurable product had already categories and websites assigned, before I start adding associated products. I thought that these parameters would have been inhereted to the associated products too. Is there some configuration parameter that could affect this?